Ошибка связанная с компилятором в Rust
Всем привет.
Я недавно захотел начать изучать яп rust, скачал rustrower, но при запуске хэллоу ворлда выводит следующую ошибку:
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1

|
а дальше там вот этот ужас:

= note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rsbegin.o" "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Temp\rustcqjL5l5\symbols.o" "C:\Users\Maxim\RustroverProjects\untitled\target\debug\deps\untitled-9116ac291e29c433.1bufwf4o565udyeyfw8dbbcce.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Maxim\RustroverProjects\untitled\target\debug\deps\untitled-9116ac291e29c433.3fyok7drm7xsx9egffn07hye7.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Maxim\RustroverProjects\untitled\target\debug\deps\untitled-9116ac291e29c433.688meb8f9n6rf5q3zerkeaw52.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Maxim\RustroverProjects\untitled\target\debug\deps\untitled-9116ac291e29c433.a5kjldcxznss1g96v0uy4bzfp.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Maxim\RustroverProjects\untitled\target\debug\deps\untitled-9116ac291e29c433.dl8blfap4d88d8cp2ymkn4fqk.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Maxim\RustroverProjects\untitled\target\debug\deps\untitled-9116ac291e29c433.dt2h02xlxyu2qkzhpekx7cf6q.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Maxim\RustroverProjects\untitled\target\debug\deps\untitled-9116ac291e29c433.5k7lzr9skxlmubb3ngwg0ygcy.rcgu.o" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-5066810ba6a3c331.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libpanic_unwind-ffe1b3cf1e858a91.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libobject-4bb2bf6b8aedb0e7.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libmemchr-b3db5392c89f893a.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libaddr2line-20a9bc570f589ab2.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libgimli-e4c6854cb2570d1b.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libwindows_targets-176ce559adcaeeab.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_demangle-f41139342d761cc4.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd_detect-a9c8a66a6ab04d67.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libhashbrown-d0a5c38fcf7e3ab4.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-34bf8e2ba505f823.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libminiz_oxide-e6c3bcb6aba3cc78.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libadler-25fd04130c61c486.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libunwind-406d0684cd466981.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcfg_if-308de7222dbe7630.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liblibc-b17ad35300ef919c.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liballoc-16133477ba5b1335.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_std_workspace_core-c9c952e3e4dff3e7.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcore-225aecd5787b5a6d.rlib" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcompiler_builtins-15f2e04ecb4aa720.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lkernel32" "-lkernel32" "-ladvapi32" "-lntdll" "-luserenv" "-lws2_32" "-ldbghelp" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-o" "C:\Users\Maxim\RustroverProjects\untitled\target\debug\deps\untitled-9116ac291e29c433.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rsend.o"
= note: E:/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh: No such file or directory␍
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

я пробовал создать конфиг .cargo, но безполезно
P.s
Нужно было просто переустановить rust
команда для его удаления:
rustup self uninstall


x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc - это пакет с компилятором gcc из MSYS2. Почему IDE не смогла установить зависимости - бог весть.
Поищите на диске E в окрестностях папки E:/gcc файл collect2.exe. Если найдётся, добавьте папку с этим файлом в PATH. Если нет, то это очень странно!
В таком случае вы можете попробовать сделать вот что:

установите MSYS2
запустите консоль MSYS2 и выполните в ней команду pacman -S x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

Добавьте в PATH пути c:\msys64\bin, c:\msys64\mingw32\bin и перезапустите IDE.
Disclaimer. Я никогда не пользовался поделиями от JetBrains, и не могу гарантировать, что этот рецепт сработает.

Я попробовал первый способ, но при добавлении каталога, содержащего collect2.exe в path ( добавил в системные и в пользовательские переменные ) у меня все равно вылазит все та же ошибка.
Что касается второго способа, у меня просто пишет это:
error: target not found: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

@MAXULTRA0 тогда увы, не знаю. Я лично программировал на Rust в VS Code под WSL2 (то есть в линуксовом окружении), поэтому у меня всё работало тип-топ. Вам же могу предложить только переустановить IDE и перезагрузиться, вдруг поможет.
